# Acesso Remoto Mysql Servidor Amazon

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-aws

Não estou conseguindo conectar com um usuário para acesso remoto no meu banco de dados. Já criei o usuário, dei permissão para acesso de qualquer ip ( % ) - ja dei permissões em cima do ip que estou usando e mesmo assim, apenas o erro : (2003) -  Can´t connect to MySql (10060) aparece quando tento conectar.

- Ja desliguei o firewall, verifiquei a instalação. Aparentemente tudo ok.

O Servidor é da Amazon - linux.

Tentei acessar o mysql através do ssh, porém ele retornar o erro (2002).

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Sugiro a você ler dois links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766014/connect-to-mysql-on-amazon-ec2-from-a-remote-server e também http://kylegoslin.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/109/ . Se os dois links nao resolverem avisa ae que dou outra olhada.

Comment: Se uma das respostas o ajudou assinale a melhor resposta e vote em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo.

Comment: Conforme as respostas anteriores, acho que você deve verificar como está o bind no arquivo my.cnf e conferir se a porta 3306 está liberada no security group da instância.

Answer (score 2):

O MySQL tem um arquivo de configuração my.cnf esse arquivo por padrão restringe o acesso, tornando possível apenas o acesso local por bloqueio de ip. Através da seguinte linha:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Se você comentar essa linha

```
# bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

E reiniciar o banco de dados ele deve respeitar os privilégios que você configurou no banco de dados como por exemplo acessar de qualquer ip '%'. Se você já fez isso e não deu certo, você deve verificar o que está ocorrendo através do arquivo de log do MySQL.

Você pode acessar esse [tutorial](http://linuxrede.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/permitir-conexao-remota-ao-banco-mysql/) com o objetivo de revisar os procedimentos que fez para permitir acesso externo ao seu banco de dados.

Comment: Ao invés comentar a linha bind-address, recomendo usar 
 "bind-address = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" onde xxx é o IP do servidor. (a sintaxe sem aspas...)

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que utilize o serviço de RDS da Amazon Web Services. Esta é a "maneira correta" de efetuar a gestão de bancos de dados MySQL na cloud da AWS. A RDS oferece diversas vantagens como backups automáticos, atualizações automáticas do servidor e um ambiente configurado para isto.

Answer (score -1):

No arquivo my.cnf ou my.ini, especifique o bind-address em uma porta diferente.

```
port = 10002
bind-address = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

O motivo em trocar a porta padrão é que a porta 3306 pode estar bloqueada na rede. Então independente de liberar o firewall do seu servidor, a rede da qual ele depende não permitirá por padrão.

Em bind-address, no lugar de `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` coloque o IP externo do seu servidor.

Por fim, verifique se está editando o arquivo correto.
Pode acontecer de ter cópias do my.cnf em locais diferente e você editar um arquivo que não tem nada a ver. Então você edita, salva, reinicia e nada acontece. rsrsrs