# Acesso a base MySql pelo connector/net

Tags: c#, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que irá acessar o banco de dados MySql apenas para consultar dados. Fiz a referência do `mysql.data.dll` e estou utilizando o acesso através do MySqlConnection.

Acontece que o sistema está retornando o seguinte erro:

> Access Denied for user 'meuusuario....'

O interessante é que eu consigo acessar a mesma base com o mesmo usuário através do SqlYog, porém não consigo através do .net.

Seria alguma configuração no usuário dentro do MySql para aceitar o acesso ?

Comment: Disponha a sua classe de conexão ou rotina @Silva

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Harry Potter. Sou novo por aqui...Como faço para incluir minha classe sem exceder o tamanho do comentário ?

Comment: Pode editar a sua questão colocar no ponto ideal e apertar no {} do editor

Comment: Esse usuário tem senha?

Comment: Se o banco de dados estiver executando em um ip diferente da sua aplicação verifique se você consegue acesso externo ao seu banco de dados e se o seu usuário tem permissão para acessar a base dados. E verifique o log do MySQL. Existe uma pergunta sobre problemas de acesso ao MySQL em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17597/acesso-remoto-mysql-servidor-amazon/22964#22964, você pode encontrar procedimentos de como configurar o MySQL para acesso externo (se esse for o caso).

Answer (score 1):

Você já verificou se o MySQL está aceitando conexões de outros hosts? Existe uma configuração no MySQL que permite que ele seja acessado somente da máquina que está instalado, ou de outros hosts.

É importante verificar na configuração (my.ini ou my.cnf, dependendo se sua instalação é windows ou unix) e ver se na seção [mysqld] as configurações estão corretas.

Alguns parâmetros que podem ser interessantes aqui são: bind-address (endereços que a conexão é permitida) e enable-named-pipe.